# c# - Custom JSON similar configuration file

Tags: c#, json, configuration, snmp, asn.1

I am working on a project that I need to read and write to a custom configuration file, from a NAT device, that looks to be very similar to JSON but with some different aspects. I have not been able to come up with a way to read/write to the file besides going through it line by line. I am hoping someone may have a suggestion to how to read/write this configuration.

Below is a template of how the configuration file is laid out.

```
SYSTEM1 = {
    Parameter1 = "1"
    Parameter2 = "abc"
    Parameter3 = "def"
    Parameter4 = "ghi"
}
SYSTEM2 = {
  MIB2 = {
    MIB2_SYSTEM = {
      sysContact = "Contact String"
      sysName = "Name String"
      sysLocation = "Location String"
    }
    MIB2_IF = {
      MIB2_IFENTRY = {
          {
          INDEX = 1
          Parameter1 = "1"
          Parameter2 = "1"
          Parameter3 = ""
          }
          {
          INDEX = 2
          Parameter1 = "1"
          Parameter2 = "1"
          Parameter3 = ""
          }
      }
    }
    MIB2_MAU = {
      MIB2_IFMAUENTRY = {
          {
          INDEX = 1.1
          Parameter1 = "value"
          Parameter2 = "value"
          }
          {
          INDEX = 2.1
          Parameter1 = "value"
          Parameter2 = "value"
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: MIB and SYSTEM sounds much like SNMP. Perhaps remove the WPF tag and add the SNMP tag instead

Comment: Thanks I did that. The configuration file is for a NAT device so that would make sense.

Comment: What's the file extension? or where does it come from?

Comment: The file extension is .cfg and it comes from a Hirschmann NAT switch.

Comment: Though it might contain some SNMP related terms, such as "MIB" and "sysContact", it is not a file format related to SNMP standards at all. You need to consult the vendor so as to learn its syntax and then find a way to parse it.